# Javascript: Confirm alert message works if i press ESC button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with confirmation messages to deleting elements of my form, but when I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> button on my keyboard, it works like I pressing "Accept" button on the popup message, is there any function that not permits that? or I'm using it wrongly?

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-e" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')" data-tooltip="Delete element"><b>X</b>
</button>
```

Comment: none of that code would delete anything - is that all the code you've written?

Answer (score 0):

This should works

```
<button type='button' class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-e" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) { document.getElementById('myform').submit(); }" data-tooltip="Delete element"><b>X</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent submitting the form by attaching a `onsubmit` Event handler; this works also with links:

```html
<!-- with a form -->

<form method="get" action="." onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-e" data-tooltip="Delete element"><b>X</b></button>
</form>

<!-- with a link -->

<a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `event` argument, and if the confirm is false (which is also while pressing `ESC` button), call `preventDefault` method on the event argument:

```html
<script>
  function ask(e) {
    if(!confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
     e.preventDefault();
     return false;
    }
  }
</script>
<form method="get" action="#" onsubmit="alert('submit')">
  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-e" data-tooltip="Delete element" 
          onclick="ask(event)">
    <b>X</b>
  </button>
</form>
```